# is there shortcut to tell typescript to knows like C# compiler getter and setter implementation?

Tags: typescript

How to tell typescript to short getter and setter generate code? i know how typescript to get and set. but i want like C#. compiler auto detect both interface and class that same name. that interface will attach to class with private member field and for method definition it default to public. it keep repetitive boring and make class contains bloat code.

```
interface Car {
    brand: string,
    model: string
}

class Car {
    brand: string 
    { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have automatic code generation of this sort.  You could possibly write a function that behaves this way when passed values like `class Car extends GetSetClass({brand: "str", model: "str"}) { }` but I'm not sure what you want to see.  How do the getters and setters behave?  Would someone write `const c = new Car()` and then `c.brand = "abc"` or `c.setBrand("abc")`?  Please provide a [mre] of how you intend to use the resulting `Car` class.

Comment: @jcalz i already mention C#. `c.brand, c.brand = string`. yes i can make interface Car to other like CarAttributes. and implements it. [see this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygQTGKwBGArpAM7IDeAUMjcvlHCACYBcyJuoA5pQL6WUEAGzgky6KMmABbAA5CI0iOHEZsnIqQrVaXCGDoNmACgCUbDnhBdttO8ij7CUEMjAALYCQB09Rkx0afkD2fUN-Yz9mC05rU1t7Gg8vXyMmZABecOYQ-mDKIA). but it horrible to keep do that for 10 attributes.

Comment: Your example [doesn't work](https://tsplay.dev/Na2GPm).  As for C#, do you intend that someone should have knowledge of C# in order to answer this question?  If so then you might want to tag it as such.  Also, what is the purpose of the auto-generated getter-setter?  Isn't a plain property going to behave similarly?

Comment: As I was saying above, you could make a class factory function like [this playground link shows](https://tsplay.dev/Wz523m).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz i want like my result, the compiler generate in background for this things. ok, i hope this typescript developer will read this and implement it. so no boilerplate. i think it will like just enable and disable compiler option.

Comment: I told you "TypeScript doesn't have automatic code generation of this sort."  Would you like an answer that just says "no" and you'll accept it?

Comment: What Javascript code would you want it to generate?

Comment: @kaya3 is not about javascript generate code result. but i want my typescript like this. but the compiler understand when interface and class have same name. it means property inside interface share with class with private modifier. and for method is default to public.

Comment: *"i want like my result, the compiler generate in background for this things"* - generate what?

Comment: I think we're not getting enough clarity here: the [code shared earlier](https://tsplay.dev/NdAn0m) by @imagesck doesn't do anything useful and even a fix that uses another property doesn't seem to be an advantage over a plain property; the question *seems* to be the compiler to do *some* sort of code generation, whatever it is, to which the answer is almost certainly "this is not possible"; then maybe there's an additional request/hope that this eventually be implemented, but the answer there is also "this will never happen because it is counter to the stated design goals of TypeScript"...

Comment: ... and unfortunately there seems to be an issue with English fluency that doesn't help with clarity.  Oh well. 